# convert event an activity node graph to an event node graph

Tags: algorithm

Does anyone know where I can find an implementation of an algorithm to convert an activity node graph (aka activity-on-node graph) to an event node graph (aka activiy-on-arrow graph)?

If you don't know what I am talking about, take a look here: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/html/page581.html

Please provide a working algo in your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is an activity node graph? What is an event node graph?

Comment: you can find it here: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus7/html/page581.html

Comment: Do you have an algorithm to do this already? What language do you want an implementation in? What are your data structures for you graph?

Comment: No, otherwise I wouldn't be asking. I am programming this in Java but, algorithms in pseudo code wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is replace every node `v` in your original graph with two nodes, `v_in` and `v_out`, connected by a single edge with weight equal to the original vertex weight.  Then replace all the original edges `(u, v)` with edges from `u_out` to `v_in` of zero weight.

Answer (score 1):

That link states how you do it:

> The activity-node graph is a
>   vertex-weighted graph. However, the
>   algorithms presented in the preceding
>   sections all require edge-weighted
>   graphs. Therefore, we must convert the
>   vertex-weighted graph into its
>   edge-weighted *dual*. In the dual graph
>   the edges represent the activities,
>   and the vertices represent the
>   commencement and termination of
>   activities. For this reason, the dual
>   graph is called an *event-node graph*.

Although I suppose it leaves out some important details. The way they suggest to convert from an activity node to event node graph is to convert every activity node into an event node edge and to add a dummy edge for activities that take multiple inputs.

Another way to construct the event node graph is to replace every activity node with an edge and two nodes, e.g.,  `A->B->C` becomes `A->A'->B->B'->C-C'`. Then, remove every node that has only one input and zero or one output and replace them with an edge of zero cost, as those event nodes don't actually do anything.

Comment: Could you please provide an algo. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach node in graph
      if count of incoming_arrows != 1
      {
         Create new node
         Assign incoming arrows from old node to new node
         Create arrow from new node to old node
         Assign cost 0 to new node             
      }
      endif
end foreach

foreach arrow in graph
         Assign cost of destination node to cost of arrow
         /* if you want ...preceded by "node name:" to get F:5 */
end foreach

Rename the nodes
```

The data structures needed are something like

```
 struct node
     node_name string
     node_cost int
 struct arrow
      arrow_form_node node
      arrow_to_node node
      arrow_cost int
```